# How we can deploy web.debug.config/web.release.config when using web setup project?

Tags: c#, installation, windows-installer

I am deploying my web application using web setup project(vs 2010).Is it possible to deploy web.debug.config/web.release.config using msi installer.

Please suggest any method.

Comment: You can add any files in your Web Application Folder. Am I missing something?